# Как ограничить ширину сайта?

Tags: html, css

Здраствуйте, есть проблема с ограничением ширины сайта, она работает но не полностью

Есть meta который ограничивает ширину сайта на 1024px

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1">`

И оно работает если зайти через телефон к примеру(в общем девайс который меньше 1024)
Так же работает если это делать через браузерную утилиту "Toggle device toolbar", где можно менять ширину экрана

Но если взять на компьютере сузить окно браузера, у сайта появится скролл внизу, да сайт будет 1024px все верно, НО мне нужно чтоб он стал меньше в размерах, без скрола, как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Задача - установить максимальную ширину контента в 1024 пикселя? Тогда вам нужно <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> и в стилях body указать max-width: 1024px и margin: 0 auto

Comment: Установить минимальную ширину сайта, чтоб он меньше чем 1024 не был, и не было скрола если я уменьшу браузер до 400px к примеру (чтоб отображалось как на телефоне)

Сайт на 1200-1920px отображается адекватно, штука в том, что нужно сделать 2 окна сайта и поставить 2 окна рядом на ноутбуке (это 1366/2), и появляется скролл, а нужно как-то все уменьшить чтоб было как на телефоне

Comment: Вы понимаете, что "минимальную ширину сайта, чтоб он меньше чем 1024 не был" и "и не было скрола если я уменьшу браузер до 400px" - взаимоисключающие требования?

Comment: Если сделать meta, и там указать 1024px, то скрола нет же на телефоне, все просто уменьшается